# how to make a list of installed apps clickable?

Tags: android, launcher

Okay i managed to make a button list all installed applications like this:

```
    public void launcher(View v){
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
        pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, mainIntent);   
        myMenu.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
```

So when I click the button a window pops up like a dialog and lists all the applications.  However, when I click any of the applications the dialog closes and nothing happens.  how can I make these applications clickable?
Code would be preferrable and I'm a noobie so please be specific in your answer.
Thanks! :)

Comment: do you want to get information of install app in your mobile?

Comment: No i just want to be able to click the applications so that they will open.

Answer (score 0):

**Here i am give one example which basically get all information of all install app from your device.**

```
class PInfo {
private String appname = "";
private String pname = "";
private String versionName = "";
private int versionCode = 0;
private Drawable icon;
private void prettyPrint() {
    Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
}
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
final int max = apps.size();
for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
}
return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
        continue ;
    }
    PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
    newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
    newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
    newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
    newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
    res.add(newInfo);
}
return res; 
}
```